# Android activity doesn't start regardless of the method used to start it

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

I've defined an android activity and it just fails to start regardless of how I try to start it. It's supposed to be launched as the main activity, but the app just hangs if I declare it as the default activity like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.StartupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionAppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="url"
                android:pathPrefix="/prefix"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="url"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've tried putting a breakpoint at the first line of `onCreate` and `Log` lines in this activity, but this activity just doesn't start. I think the source code of the activity is irrelevent since it doesn't ever start. Please let me know if it's needed. I tried setting another activity as the default one and start `StartupActivity` from it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (! AppRuntime.b) {
        AppRuntime.b = true;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    }
// other stuff
}
```

But the result is similar to what I see when `StartupActivity` is the default activity. The breakpoints in this activity work as expected. The problem arises when the `StartupActivity` is started. What's causing this problem?

Note: `StartupActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` and overrides only `onCreate` and `onActivityResult`.

Edit: here's the activity code:

```
public class StartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sp;
    String deepLink = "";

    final int SIGNUP_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    final int TUTORIAL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addressInvitation();

        sp = App.getSharedPreferences();

        MobileAds.initialize(this, Utils.getAdmobID());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        //load the ad
//        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
//        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        Log.d("DEBUGGING", "calling bootstrap");

        bootstrapApp();
    }


    private void bootstrapApp() {
        if (! sp.contains("signed_in")) {
            sp.edit().clear().apply();
            Log.d("DEBUGGING", "starting signup activity");
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SignUp.class), SIGNUP_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else if (! sp.contains("isFirstTime")) {
            Log.d("DEBUGGING", "starting tutorial");
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, TutorialsActivity.class), TUTORIAL_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            Log.d("DEBUGGING", "going to splash screen");
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class));
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SIGNUP_REQUEST_CODE:
                Log.d("DEBUGGING", "signup returned");
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    sp.edit()
                            .putBoolean("signed_in", true)
                            .apply();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case TUTORIAL_REQUEST_CODE:
                Log.d("DEBUGGING", "tutorial returned");
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    sp.edit()
                            .putBoolean("isFirstTime", true)
                            .apply();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
        bootstrapApp();
    }



    private void addressInvitation() {
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
                        if (data == null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get the deep link
                        deepLink = data.getLink().toString();

                        // Extract invite
                        FirebaseAppInvite invite = FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(data);
                        if (invite != null) {
                            String invitationId = invite.getInvitationId();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e("HandleInvitaiton", "COULD NOT HANDLE");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing any kind of background processes inside the same?

Comment: App is hanging because your main thread or UI thread has too much task or process. Make sure your main thread has minimal amount of task.

Comment: @SalmanKhan No I'm not.

Comment: @JaiminThakkar The activity simply fails to start. The app hangs in the sense that there's nothing on the screen. The behavior is different from when the app hangs because of overloaded UI thread.

Comment: Can you share the full activity code so we can get an idea?

Comment: @SalmanKhan I've put the activity code in the question.

Comment: @saga show the application error log.

Comment: Try commenting all the code and then run the application, just keep setContentView method in OnCreate and then check whether it's working or not.

Comment: @SalmanKhan I commented everything except the setContentView and `Log.d`, yet it didn't work.

Comment: @SalmanKhan There were a couple of red lines in the logcat window: `10-30 16:00:51.932 20613-20692/com.app.app D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
10-30 16:00:51.933 20613-20692/com.app.app E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb4488800 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xa11dc9e0 arg=0x0
    ssl=0xb4488800 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
10-30 16:00:51.954 20613-20692/com.app.app D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb4488800 cert_verify_callback => 1`

Comment: I think there is a problem with the FireBase thing that you are using, try to comment the data tag also from Manifest file and then check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem. You're using

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

instead of

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

You're overriding the wrong method.

Comment: Unconsciously I was aware that there was something different about the `onCreate` of `StartupActivity`, thanks for pointing that out.